# Can I use autofocus on an element with contenteditable?

Tags: text, input, contenteditable, autofocus

I'm using the `contenteditable` attribute on a `<div>` in order to make it act as a text field on demand (for users to rename something). But I want to enable `autofocus` on it as well, so users can begin typing immediately (the `<div>` always has `contenteditable` enabled initially).

Is this valid and/or possible? Or will I have to switch to a standard text input?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll have to do it with JavaScript in most browsers, I think. And it won't work on iOS, which only allows programmatic use of `focus()` in an event handler of a genuine user interaction (such as a `click` or touch-related event).

Also, be aware that if there other inputs on the page, it's possible the user may focus on one of those before the document has completely loaded, in which case it is then very annoying for the user to find that the focus has been moved from under them when the `load` event does fire, so you should use the inputs' `focus` events to track this.

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("editable").focus();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: If the HTML5 autofocus attribute starts supporting contenteditable elements, then that might be a better solution. However currently it only works with form elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_autofocus_attribute

Comment: Actually you don't need `onload` for `focus`.

Answer (score 2):

For future viewers:

I think I may have a slightly more elegant solution.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $("[autofocus]").focus();
});
```

So, once the page loads... BAM jQuery focuses on the element with the 'autofocus' attribute!

You could play around with the selector to get exactly what you want.